# How to pull out a pre-defined factor in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to non-dimensionalize the displacement function for the deflection of a cantilevered beam (just for some context).

I've solved the governing differential equation to describe the deflection of the beam to get [image: equation]. In addition, I know that I can "remove" e, i, and k from the equation altogether by putting them in terms of some factor. From the solution manual of my textbook, I know that the factor, eta, is equal to [image: this].

Since I know that eta is "contained" in my equation, I know that I can restructure it to replace all terms with e, i, and k with eta. Is there some way to do this easily with Mathematica?

I have tried the `FactorTerms[]` function, but it only factors out numerical values, it won't factor out variables. It's easy enough to do by hand, now I'm just curious to see if I can do it in Mathematica to save myself some time in the future.

Thanks, and I apologize if there is already an answer to this elsewhere. I have looked quite a bit and couldn't find anything.

Comment: In addition, is there a way to pull out eta if I don't know what it is? Essentially, I want to pull out all terms related to k, e, and i in the original equation.

Comment: Found an answer. First, the factor was not contained in the original equation I posted. It was contained in (e*i)*w(x). Second, I was able to accomplish what I wanted with the `Eliminate` function. By setting eta == the stuff in the second image above and eliminating k, I got my function in terms of x and L only, and was able to easily recognize the rest of the steps required to non-dimensionalize completely. Thanks to all who read! Please, if you have a better solution, I'm always looking for better ways to do things!

Comment: You can add your answer as real answer, not comment and confirm it. In this way, you will prevent to reading question that is solved by other people.